# XPath based on attribute value

Tags: xslt, xpath

I am trying to get an attribute based on a condition, my XML is

```
<listitems xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" 
xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" 
xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" 
xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
<rs:data ItemCount="2">
    <z:row ows_Attachments=";#/Attachments/79/164351;#" ows_ID="79" />
    <z:row ows_Attachments=";#/Attachments/80/164352;#" ows_ID="80" />
</rs:data>
</listitems>
```

I want to get ows_ID where ows_Attachments ends with a specific number, for example

I Want 79 if ows_Attachments endswith or contain 164351;#

If any regex available to remove all namespaces etc and then if it makes easy for processing, I am open to that option as well.

Answer (score -1):

Strictly speaking, with XPath you can select the attribute with :

```
//*[local-name()="row" and contains(@ows_Attachments,"/164351")]/@ows_ID
```

And extract the value with :

```
string(//*[local-name()="row" and contains(@ows_Attachments,"/164351")]/@ows_ID)
```

Output : 79

Comment: There should never be a reason to use a hack like `*[local-name()="row"`.